# Get a Result Set using Callable statement

Tags: java, sql, sql-server, jdbc, callable-statement

I have a sql file as follows(Pseudocode).

```
Begin
Create Table1
Create Table2
Insert values into Table1 by joining 20 different tables
Insert values into Table2 by joining 16 different tables
End
```

When I execute this in MS Sql server, I get output with several columns. The same SQL Query I am storing in a physical location in my computer and trying to obtain the ResultSet in Java. Here is what I am trying.

```
Connection conn = null;
Class.forName(driver);
conn = DriverManager.getConnection(dbUrl + dbName, userName,password);
FileInputStream input = new FileInputStream("E:\\Query2.sql");
CallableStatement cs = conn.prepareCall(IOUtils.toString(input));                
cs.execute();
ResultSet rs = cs.getResultSet();
System.out.println("Done" + rs);
```

When I run this, I am getting Result set as null, Where am I going wrong? Please help.

Comment: You never check the value of `cs.execute()`. Please read the Javadoc which explains the meaning of the return values of [`execute()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#execute()), [`getResultSet`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#getResultSet()) and [`getMoreResults`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#getMoreResults()). More than likely the initial result is an update count instead of a  result set.

Answer (score 0):

When you want to execute your code using `.sql` file you need to use `ScriptRunner` class from `java`

```
ScriptRunner scriptRunner = new ScriptRunner(connection, true, true);
scriptRunner.runScript(new FileReader("script.sql"));
```

also you can use

```
MysqlDataSource ds = new MysqlDataSource();
ds.setServerName("hostname");
ds.setUser("username");
ds.setPassword("password");

JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate(ds);

BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("script.sql"));
LineNumberReader fileReader = new LineNumberReader(in); 
String query = JdbcTestUtils.readScript(fileReader);
```

Now you can use JDBCtemplate.query to query your db

The ResultSet required will be passed as parameter to the extractData of ResultSetExtractor implementation or to the mapRow of the RowMapper implementation. So the processing of the ResultSet will be done in the extractData or mapRow implementation and we will return the Collection/Object or type of data you wanted

```
anyclass object = jdbcTemplate.query(query, new ResultSetExtractor<anyclass>() {
        @Override
        public YourClass extractData(ResultSet rs) throws SQLException, DataAccessException {
            // processing of the ResultSet
            return result;
        }
    });
```

This helped me, you can also try!

Comment: But this does not get me the ResultSet? Does it?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have to use method [prepareCall](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Connection.html#prepareCall%28java.lang.String,%20int,%20int%29) with additional parameters and, possible, additional parameters are required for method [execute](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#execute%28java.lang.String,%20int%5B%5D%29).